# Jquery UI Tooltip doesn't show up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

What am I doing wrong?

I have this simple code:

```
<img width="50" height="50" src="http://www.fancyicons.com/free-icons/112/must-have/png/256/remove_256.png">
```

Javascript

```
$("img[src$='remove_256.png']").tooltip({ content : "Example"});
```

But tooltip doesn't display.

This example works

```
<img title="Example 2" width="50" height="50" src="http://www.fancyicons.com/free-icons/112/must-have/png/256/remove_256.png">
```

Javascript

```
$("img[src$='remove_256.png']").tooltip();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m2u8p/3/

I don't understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a title attribute to your img tag and it'll work.  It can be empty because you're going to set it in javascript, but it has to exist.  You can use a different attribute, but title is the default. http://jsfiddle.net/m2u8p/4/

```
<img class="1" width="50" height="50" title="" src="http://www.fancyicons.com/free-icons/112/must-have/png/256/remove_256.png">

<img class="2" title="Example 2" width="50" height="50" src="http://www.fancyicons.com/free-icons/112/must-have/png/256/remove_256.png">

$(".1").tooltip({ content : "Example"});
$(".2").tooltip();
```

Comment: Title is required.... why!!!? anyway so many programing things are beyond my understanding. Thanks!!!